# How to declare a Stream-like interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The npm package [csv-parse](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse) implements a Node.JS Stream like API:

```
const parser = parse();
parser.on('readable', () => {
  let record: any;    // <-- it should be string[]
  while (record = parser.read()) {
    output.push(record);
  }
});
```

Its [type declaration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/csv-parse/) is:

```
interface parse {
  (options?: options): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
}
```

The return type of `parse` is `NodeJS.ReadWriteStream`, which has a method `read` returning `string | Buffer`.

```
interface ReadWriteStream extends ReadableStream, WritableStream {
  // ...
}

interface ReadableStream extends EventEmitter {
  read(size?: number): string | Buffer;
  // ...
}
```

By this definition, I can't define the variable `let record: any = parser.read()` to its actual type `string[]`.

I have tried to modify the type definition of csv-parse like this:

```
interface ParserStream extends NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {
    read(size?: number): string[];    
}

interface parse {
    (options?: options): ParserStream;
}
```

It doesn't work because TypeScript not allow to extend an interface and change method's return type.

What I can think of is to change NodeJS Stream to a generic type like:

```
interface GenericReadableStream <T> extends EventEmitter {
  read(size?: number): T
  // ...
}

interface ReadableStream extends GenericReadableStream <string | Buffer> {}
```

Then I can define:

```
interface ParserStream extends GenericReadableStream <string[]> {}
```

I don't know if it's a good way. It impacts a lot in current Node.JS type definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, CsvParser implementation uses steams in [object mode](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse/blob/master/lib/index.js#L83), so `string | Buffer` isn't really a good return type for `CsvParser.read`.

Fortunately, TypeScript allows to extend an interface and change method's return type to `any`. So you can change `csv-parse` type definition to

```
  interface CsvParser extends NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {
      read(size?: number): any;
```

allowing this code to compile

```
let record: string[];  
while (record = parser.read()) {
```

But this is not strict enough, because this will compile too:

```
let record: number[];  
while (record = parser.read()) {
```

To disallow that, you somehow need to declare an interface that changes `read` return type to `string[]`. You can't do that in an interface that directly extends `ReadWriteStream` because `string[]` is incompatible with `string | Buffer`. However it's possible if you add intermediate step - an interface that extends `ReadWriteStream` and has return type for `read` compatible with both. It can be an intersection type of `any` and the desired type for which we can use generic parameter `T`:

```
interface ObjectStream<T> extends NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {
    read(size?: number): any & T;
}
```

Then you can have CsvParser extending it:

```
interface CsvParser extends ObjectStream<string[]> {
    read(size?: number): string[];
}
```

That way, you still need to modify `csv-parser` type definitions, but there is no need to change type definitions for node streams.

NOTE: the first attempt at the answer was

```
  interface CsvParser extends NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {
      read(size?: number): any & string[];
```

which, as @aleung noticed, is no different from

```
  interface CsvParser extends NodeJS.ReadWriteStream {
      read(size?: number): any;
```

because it still allows to assign the result of read to a variable of any type.

Comment: I tested on TypeScript 2.0.3. Intersaction of `any` and `string[]` is `any`. So it's still possible to assign to `number[]`.

Comment: Oh yes I oversimplified the answer and did not check. You need one intermediate interface between ReadWriteStream and CsvParser in which you override `read` to return `any & string[]`, then in CsvParser you can override it to return only `string[]`. I will check again and update the answer.